# Matching elements in seperate xml files with xlst and then printing sibling

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How would one look for matching elements between two xml documents and then print the sibling of one? For example:

customer.xml

```
<customers>
  <customer>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <orderid>1234</orderid>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>Sarah White</name>
    <orderid>4321</orderid>
  </customer>
</customers>
```

orders.xml

```
<orders>
  <order>
    <id>1234</id>
    <product>laptop</product>
  </order>
  <order>
    <id>4321</id>
    <product>television</product>
  </order>
</orders>
```

output.xml

```
<backlog>
  <customer>
    <name>John Smith</name>
    <product>laptop</product>
  </customer>
  <customer>
    <name>Sarah White</name>
    <product>television</product>
  </customer>
</backlog>
```

I want to make it so the .xslt displays the name as usual however it should scan the second document for an `<id>` matching it's `<orderid>` and then display the `<product>` instead.

Displaying the `<name>` is easy enough but I'm not sure how the logic of getting `<product>` works. This is what I have:

```
<xsl:if test="document('customer.xml')/customers/customer/orderid = document('orders.xml')/orders/order/id">
  <product><xsl:value-of select="document('orders.xml')/orders/order/product" /></product>
</xsl:if>
```

however this gives me the result of:

```
<product>laptop television</product>
```

for each `<customer>`

Answer (score 1):

Using XSLT 2.0 you can easily cross-reference between documents with e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="orders-url" select="'orders.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="orders-doc" select="document($orders-url)"/>

<xsl:key name="order" match="order" use="id"/>

<xsl:template match="customer">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="name, key('order', orderid, $orders-doc)/product"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then also add

```
<xsl:template match="customers">
  <backlog>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </backlog>
</xsl:template>
```

and you are done.

With XSLT 1.0 you can also use a key but then need e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="customer">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
    <xsl:variable name="id" select="orderid"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$orders-doc">
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('order', $id)/product"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('orders.xml')"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <backlog>
            <xsl:for-each select="customers/customer">
                <xsl:variable name="ID" select="orderid"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$lookup/orders/order/id[.=$ID]/following-sibling::product"></xsl:copy-of>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </backlog>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```